# Given QuantLib Python VanillaSwap object, how to get the iborIndex of the swap object?

Tags: swaps, python, quantlib

I'm currently using QuantLib Python. Let's say that I've got a VanillaSwap object:

```
import QuantLib as ql
swap_obj = ql.VanillaSwap(... , iborIndex , ...)
```

How can I find out what is the underlying iborIndex of the swap object?

I've tried the following already, but none of the following works:

```
swap_obj.index
swap_obj.iborIndex
swap_obj.index()
swap_obj.iborIndex()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit awkward. Cashflows and indexes are stored as pointers to their base class and you can't cast them directly from Python, so the module provides a few helper functions from that.  You can do something like:

```
first_coupon = as_floating_rate_coupon(swap_obj.floatingLeg()[0])
ibor = as_iborindex(first_coupon.index())
```

(Using, e.g., just `first_coupon.index()` would give you an instance of `FloatingRateIndex`, so it wouldn't have the complete interface of `IborIndex`.)